# <span> or <p> to display one body text for 2 or more tags

Tags: css, html

So i have a body of text that i've split into 3 columns (newspaper strip style). 
That works fine. However on my resize compatibility i want to display just one column for screens below a certain size.

the code -
HTML

```
<div class="columnContainer">
    <p>
        <span>Some text here that will display in the first column.
        </span>
        <span>Some text here that will display in the second column.
        </span>
        <span>Some text here that will display in the third column.
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

the CSS

```
 .columnContainer{
        position:relative;
    width:100%;
    max-width:750px;
    height:auto;
    min-height:145px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    }

    .columnContainer span{
    position:relative;
    width:29%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin:0 2%;
    text-align:justify;
    }
```

and then the resize CSS

```
@media (max-width:630px){
    .columnContainer span{
        width:100%;
        display:inline;
    }
```

I was hoping that the text would be displayed as one solid block.
Like:

> Some body of text for first column. Some body of text for second column. Some body of text for third column.

However- The output display:

> Some body of text for 
>   first column. 
>   Some body of text for 
>   second column. 
>   Some body of text for 
>   third column.

Comment: It looks like you would need to apply the `display: inline;` to the `columncontainer` as well as any intermediate block containers based on `@media`.

Comment: Okay - so the question didn't format correctly. What happens is between each span there is a line-break that splits the text into three blocks on top of each other. However it is just one body of text and the original splits are put in at mid sentence in all 3 columns. so when the text displays at one block in the resize it should all run smoothly together and not have the line break.

Comment: @abiessu - I've tried that with no success.

Comment: I've been known to be wrong on occasion, go with the answers below.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to set a `width` to `inline` elements.

Add `display: block;` to your `span` element and it will automatically become full-width. You don't even need the `width: 100%;` and of course you need to prevent it from floating by `float: none;` like so:

```
@media (max-width:630px){
    .columnContainer span{
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: @C-Link, yep ) sometimes it happens )

Comment: I have to set a width to break the columns into 3 for the original screen layout. If i remove the "width:100%;" then it will display the columns as a 3rd of the screen size where as on smaller screens it needs to stretch across as the width as one column. not 3.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
@media (max-width:630px){
    .columnContainer span{
        width:100%;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

inline element can't have width and height properties so you need to set display to inline-block or block.

Comment: I would only add `float: none;` to your answer, because without it - they will still be floating..

Comment: @skip405, they won't because they have `width` set to `100%`.

Comment: @matewka, oh yes, they will ) setting the `width` does not remove the `float` property ) To tell you the truth even setting `display: inline-block;` will NOT make them trully `inline-block` (see the computed style of floated elements if you doubt me)... Floats always have `display: block;` and nothing will beat it. Although I agree that it will be almost impossible to see the difference in this case as they'll occupy 100%...

Comment: I don't doubt you and you don't need to `tell me the truth` because I know CSS. I just wanted to say what I said in the previous comment. Maybe I wasn't precise enough. Let's say _visually_ they won't flow. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The declaration in the media query is in addition to the other declarations. Therefore you must revert the `float: left` with a `float: none`

```
@media (max-width:630px) {
    .columnContainer span {
        display:inline;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2GvR/)